# C# Read from a Networkstream

Tags: c#, networking, stream

Im trying to send an object( in my case an image) over a networkstream.. however- im not getting the full image..

This is the client code:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


       TcpClient c = new TcpClient();
        c.Connect("10.0.0.4", 10);
       NetworkStream ns = c.GetStream();

       Bitmap f = GetDesktopImage();
       byte[] buffer = imageToByteArray(f);
       byte[] len = BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length);        
       MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
           stream.Write(len, 0, len.Length);
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.Position = 0;
            stream.CopyTo(ns);

    }
```

As you  can see i write the entire content **to a  regular MemoryStream** first(because i dont want to use twice the `NetworkStream`- only then, i copy the `MemoryStream` content into the `NetworkStream`.

The server code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpListener tl = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10);
        tl.Start();
        TcpClient c = tl.AcceptTcpClient();
          network = new NetworkStream(c.Client);

          byte[] buff = new byte[4];
          network.Read(buff, 0, 4);
          int len = BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 0);

          buff = new byte[len];
          network.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
          pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(buff);
          Thread th = new Thread(method);


    }
```

Now when i run both application im getting only the top part of the captured image... It's even more odd because writing directly both to a network stream works perfect... For example:

```
 ns.Write(len, 0, len.Length);
   ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

This would work fine and i'll get the full image in the other side.. but i dont want to use it twice(it's just an example, in my real project i would have to use it alot so i would like to reduce the network usage as much as posibble ,and not trigger it for every single data).

Why it's not working  using simply the `CopyTo` method?

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: `network.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);` doesn't have to read `buff.Length` bytes. check its return value and keep reading till you read `len` bytes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server code you are ignoring the result of NetworkStream.Read which is the actual number of bytes read. This can be **less** than the number of bytes you actually requested. You need to keep calling Read until you have received all the bytes you need.

The differences you seeing between 1 or multiple writes has to do with the buffering/timing in the network stack. I suspect you just getting lucky receiving the image when doing a single write - this will not always be the case! You **need** to handle the result of Read as explained above.

Code Example:

```
void ReadBuffer(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int num;
    int num2 = 0;
    do
    {
        num2 += num = _stream.Read(buffer, offset + num2, count - num2);
    }
    while ((num > 0) && (num2 < count));
    if (num2 != count)
        throw new EndOfStreamException
            (String.Format("End of stream reached with {0} bytes left to read", count - num2));
    }
```

Comment: alright.. buy may i ask you why when i directly write to a networkstream it just immidently read the whole content? @Kevin